# at the remove of nearly seventy years - should "even" be inserted at the front?

Tags: meaning

> But, at the remove of nearly seventy years—in an age of image profusion and instantly visible atrocities—the first five reels of the so-called Hitchcock film are of historical significance, both in the struggle to confront the discovery of the Nazi atrocities, and, of course, in the politics of the postwar era.
>   [Source](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/movies/2014/01/hitchcock-and-the-holocaust.html)

Is it more accurate to add "even" before "at the remove of...?"

Answer (score 2):

SHORT ANSWER:
No.

LONG ANSWER:
To write *even* would imply that readers should expect the lapse of seventy years to *reduce* the historical significance of the film, and that it is surprising to find that it is still of historical significance.

This is the opposite of what the author means. Mr. Brody is contrasting what the film was in the 1940s— its original purpose was “to confront German citizens with their government’s crimes”—with what it is today: an historical document which recalls the “memory” not only of the Holocaust itself but also of the first horror of its discovery.